# dynamically create a 2d array of strings

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

i'm new to C and whilst working on a problem i'm struggling to dynamically create a 2d array of string values that i can access like things[i][j]. so far i can create a 1 d array of strings and access it like thing[i] but im stumped on how to do that for a 2d array with the rows and columns needed decided for a variable called total.

```
total = 7
char* *students = malloc(sizeof(char*) * total);

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    students[i]="kitty";
}

for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%s",students[i]);
}
```

this is what i have soo far but i cant do for a 2d array.

ive already created a 1d array of strings

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate a two-dimensional array like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//...

char ( *students )[7] = malloc( sizeof( char[5][7] ) );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    strcpy( students[i], "kitty" );
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    puts( students[i] );
}

//...

free( students );
```

Another approach is to allocate a one-dimensional array of pointers that in turn will point to one dimensional arrays of characters as for example

```
char **students = malloc( 5 * sizeof( char * ) );

fir ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    students[i] = malloc( 7 * sizeof( char ) );
}

fir ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    strcpy( students[i], "kitty" );
}

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    puts( students[i] );
}

//...

for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    free( students[i] );
}
free( students );
```

Comment: does that dynamically set the size of the array so for example if the program was to change the value of total would the size of the array change

Comment: @arka581 In this case you need to reallocate the array using standard function realloc.